# A question related to the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. It it true that for every $c\in[a,b]$, there exists some $(a_0, b_0)$ such that

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b_0)-f(a_0)}{b_0 - a_0}\,? $$

Comment: You need to ensure that there are no points of inflection for $f$ in $(a, b) $ otherwise the result is false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not necessarily. Consider for example $f(x)=x^3$. Then $f'(0)=0$, but there are no $a$ and $b$ such that
$$\frac{a^3-b^3}{a-b}=0$$
without having $a=b$.